# Icefaces - ace:datatable with more than 1 value

Tags: object, datatable, row, icefaces, ace-editor

I would like to have an ace:datatable where I can compare an "old" object against a "new" object. 
Unfortunately I can only use List of Object to handle only one Object per row. Is it possible to handle more than one object per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both lists will have always the same size you could try something like this.

```
                    <ace:dataTable value="#{bean.oldList}" var="item" rowIndexVar="index">
                    <ace:column headerText="Old Value">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}"/>
                    </ace:column>
                    <ace:column headerText="New Value">                            
                            <h:outputText value="#{bean.newList[index].value}"/>                              
                    </ace:column>                  
                </ace:dataTable>
```

However i don't really like this because it can lead to index out of bound exception
Perhaps you could also try playing with nested datatables.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the Tag rowIndexVar!